# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET (Windows Phone) - ArcGISLocalTiledLayer Issue

Tags: arcgis-10.1, c#, .net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, windows-phone

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 client for our company ArcGIS maps. Online layers works fine, but I need to deliver offline maps (Map Tile Package - .tpk file) to users with bad connectivity. My problem is that not every user has device with Storage Card, and I try to save .tpk file to Internal Storage of Phone, i.e. Pictures Library folder.

I can succesfully read .tpk file from there to StorageFile, so the app has the permission to read, but I cannot initialize ArcGISLocalTiledLayer from this file. Even when I copy file to App Local Store, still cannot initialize ArcGISLocalTiledLayer from this file. I tried different path formats:

```
// Settings.LocalDataPath = "C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Camera Roll\\ArcGIS\\MS_PM_BaseMap.tpk"; - when loading from Pictures Library
// Settings.LocalDataPath = "ms-appdata:///local/MS_PM_BaseMap.tpk"; - when file is in Local Storage
// Settings.LocalDataPath = "isostore:/MS_PM_BaseMap.tpk"; - another try...

var tpk = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(Settings.LocalDataPath);
tpk.ID = "tpk";
await tpk.InitializeAsync();
```

on InitializeAsync() I get exception "Failed to open file. May not be a valid tile package.". When file is saved on StorageCard, initialization works fine. Is it possible to use .tpk file from any location in phone's internal storage?

Answer (score 1):

FYI (for others with the same issue), you'll find additional discussion here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/162953